# Is there a way to get class name using inherited superclass method?

Tags: java, oop

Assume I have two classes

```
class A {
public static String getMyClassname()
 {
    // return the class name it was called on
 }
}


class B extends A{}
```

Is there any utility in java that allows me if I call  `A.getMyClassname()`  I'd get  `A` 
and if i call  `B.getMyClassname()`, I'd get `B` ?

Comment: I have spent enough time searching on google & stackoverflow for this question and I adhere to questions rules here. 
So if you see this question is not useful and gonna to down-vote it, please at least explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you make the method non-static

```
class A {

    public String getMyClassname() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}


class B extends A {}
```

You can then do

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

System.out.println(a.getMyClassname());
System.out.println(b.getMyClassname());
```

Output

```
A
B
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use static ? Just override that function without using static and then do your method call.

Something like this :

```
class A {
   public String getMyClassname()
     {
       return "A"
     }
 }


  class B extends A {
   @override
   public String getMyClassname()
     {
       return "B"
     }
 }
```